# How to do st_intersection in PostGIS using R

Tags: postgis, r, polygon, sf

I have a large polygon file in the form of .gdb (`mygdb`, ~10gb) and I need to crop it using another polygon shapefile (`myshp`, ~10mb). I want to do this PostGIS database using R so that it will be faster and R won't crash. I already have them exported to my postGIS database. (say, `schema = myschema`, `table = mytab1` for `mygdb` and `table = mytab2` for `myshp`) I know if I have them locally saved I can do using `sf::st_intersection(x,y)`. But I am finding it hard to find any proper help on how to do this without importing them in R. I understand I need to write some `SQL` code inside the `st_intersection` to do this in PostGIS database without importing them again in R. I am a beginner in `SQL` and not sure what exactly to write inside the function. Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: You should be able to use one of R's PostgreSQL access packages and do the query directly on the database, and not using R's `st_intersection` function at all.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind illustrating this with an example or pointing me to a guide to get me started?

Comment: Install https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html and work through basic SQL examples of how to run SQL. Then read PostGIS docs for spatial operations. No time for full answer right now, hope this is better than nothing.